# How to print multiple page using e.HasMorePages?

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I want to print data from datagridview,
however when data exceed than one page it is missing. I try to use e.HasMorePages to print multiple pages. I try and search for example for 3 hours ago but unfortunately it does not work

Now when I click print, It is print only the same page without stopping.

Please help.

```
Private Sub PrintColorConsumption_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintColorConsumption.PrintPage
    Dim x As Integer = 100
    Dim y As Integer = 25
    Dim header As Boolean = True
    'draw headers
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Do While (j < Me.DataGridView3.Columns.Count)
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(x, y, Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).Width, Me.DataGridView3.ColumnHeadersHeight)
        Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
        If (Not (Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).HeaderText) Is Nothing) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)
        End If
        x = (x + rect.Width)
        j = (j + 1)
    Loop
    x = 100
    y = (y + Me.DataGridView3.ColumnHeadersHeight)
    'draw rows
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView3.Rows
        j = 0
        Do While (j < Me.DataGridView3.Columns.Count)
            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
            cell = row.Cells(j)
            Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
            Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
            If (Not (cell.Value) Is Nothing) Then
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)
            End If
            x = (x + rect.Width)
            j = (j + 1)
        Loop
        x = 100
        y = (y + row.Height)
        '----------------------New page----------------------------
        If (y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom) Then       'Print new page
            e.HasMorePages = True
            y = 20
        End If
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing requires you to maintain **where** you are within the data that you are printing for every PrintPage event.  The way you have your variables declared they go out of scope and are set to their initial values every time the event is raised.

See if the following code, which wasn't tested, helps.  Note that a variable was declared outside of the event handler to keep track of the current row.

```
Dim whRow As Integer = 0
Private Sub PrintColorConsumption_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintColorConsumption.PrintPage
    Dim x As Integer = 100
    Dim y As Integer = 25
    Dim header As Boolean = True
    'draw headers
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Do While (j < Me.DataGridView3.Columns.Count)
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(x, y, Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).Width, Me.DataGridView3.ColumnHeadersHeight)
        Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
        If (Not (Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).HeaderText) Is Nothing) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.DataGridView3.Columns(j).HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)
        End If
        x = (x + rect.Width)
        j = (j + 1)
    Loop
    x = 100
    y = (y + Me.DataGridView3.ColumnHeadersHeight)
    'draw rows
    For whRow = whRow To Me.DataGridView3.RowCount - 1
        Dim drow As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGridView3.Rows(whRow)
        j = 0
        Do While (j < Me.DataGridView3.Columns.Count)
            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
            cell = drow.Cells(j)
            Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
            Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
            If (Not (cell.Value) Is Nothing) Then
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)
            End If
            x = (x + rect.Width)
            j = (j + 1)
        Loop
        x = 100
        y = (y + drow.Height)
        '----------------------New page----------------------------
        If (y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom) Then       'Print new page
            e.HasMorePages = True
            y = 20
        End If
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Now number of pages is correct, but the second page has only the table header, the rest of data still on first page and overlap with data of first page because set y=20 (The line after e.HasMorePages = True). If I delete line y=20, the overlap data will disappear but not show in the second page also
Any ideas ?

Comment: Just add "Exit sub" after that line, now it work perfectly.
Thank you so much @dbasnett.

Comment: @JenneyMC  Didn't get to test it... Sorry.